# Recommendation tag synonym of Recommendations

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonym-request

The tags [recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) and [recommendations](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recommendations) seem to be synonyms. Unfortunately I do not have the required score in these tags to propose a synonym. I figured this was the next best thing :)

Answer (score 5):

I edited the [single topic](https://superuser.com/questions/309038/free-bluetooth-software-for-file-transfer) in [recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) to more specifically use [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec).

It's probably not worth it to create a synonym.

---

I also feel that [recommendation](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/recommendation) is dangerously close to being useless. In the (probably very few) cases where neither [software-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/software-rec) nor [hardware-rec](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/hardware-rec) fit, it doesn't exactly help.